# Exiting from a loop

Tags: c, while-loop, standards, break

The tool I use to check coding standard complaints on the code below that "there can only be a single exit from the loop". It says the "while (len < totalLen)" loop below has an extra way to exit. 
It says "need single entry and single exit for all constructs (functions, loops)". I am puzzled by this since the while loop it is complaining has only single exit criteria.

What is the meaning of single entry and single exit criteria and how is the below code violating it. 
The if condition in the while loop is necessary. How do I keep it and be complaint to the coding standard

```
   while (len < (totalLen))
    {

    switch (*(structAddr  + len - 1))
        {

        case CASEA:                     //8 byte data


            while (len < totalLen)
                {
                if ((*(structAddr  + len) == CASE0))                           //this means there is no 8 byte data left to swap
                    {
                    arr[len] = *(nvStruct + len);
                    break;
                    }

                arr[len]     = *(structAddr  + len + 1);
                arr[len + 1] = *(structAddr  + len);
                len          = len + 2;

                }

            break;


        case CASEB:                     //2 byte data


            while ((*(structAddr + len + 1) != CASE0) && (len < totalLen))
                {

                arr[len] = ((*(structAddr + len) << 16) & (0xffff0000)) |
                           ((*(structAddr + len) >> 16) & (0x0000ffff));
                len++;
                }

            break;


        default:                      //4 byte data - no swap needed

            arr[len] = *(structAddr + len);


        }

    len++;
    }


}
```

Comment: It should complain about how inconsistent the code is.

Comment: Please give us a complete working example and indent properly your code

Answer (score 2):

Because your loop has a condition and a break if another condition is satisfied, the *inner* `while` loop.

```
while (len < totalLen)
{
    if ((*(structAddr + len) == CASE0)) // It is complaining here
    {
        arr[len] = *(structAddr+len);
        break;
    }
    arr[len] = *(structAddr + len + 1);
    arr[len + 1] = *(structAddr + len);
    len = len + 2;
}
```

The code above exits the loop,

1. If `len < totalLen`
2. If `structAddr[len] == CASE0`

youd should write it in a way that there is only one stop condition, or evaluate both conditions in a single place, like

```
do {
    if ((*(structAddr + len) == CASE0))
    {
        arr[len] = *(structAddr + len);
        // I don't know if it will naturally stop here
        // but certainly, the algorithm is too dark to see
        // that's why this is discouraged.
    } else {
        arr[len] = *(structAddr + len + 1);
    }
    arr[len + 1] = *(structAddr + len);
    len = len + 2;
} while (len < totalLen);
```

I still don't know if this is correct because your code looks bad, and don't use things like `*(structAddr + len)` in real code, use `structAddr[len]` instead which is simpler to interpret and read.

Comment: do
                    {
                    if ((nvStruct[len] == BYTETYPE))                         
                        {
                        arr[len] = nvStruct[len];

                        }
                    else
                        {

                        arr[len]     = nvStruct[len + 1];
                        arr[len + 1] = nvStruct[len];
                        len          = len + 2;
                        }

                    }
                while ((len < totalLen) && !(nvStruct[len] == BYTETYPE));

Answer (score 0):

This approach might solve your problem but not sure.

```
do {
    if ((*(structAddr + len) == CASE0))
        arr[len] = *(structAddr + len);
    else 
        arr[len] = *(structAddr + len + 1);

    arr[len + 1] = *(structAddr + len);
    len = len + 2;
} while (len < totalLen &&  !(*(structAddr + len) == CASE0));
```